Azure Cyclecloud
I am trying to create the azure cyclecloud cluster using terraform, can anyone help in this?
I created the azure cycle cloud virtual machine but now I am unable to create the cluster using Terraform.
after Cycle cloud server creation we can open the configuration file using https://serverip
below mentioned screen will be open .
Once we will select the Slurm or any other cluster it should open below mentioned page and these configuration should be done by terraform


Can you please share the code you tried so far @anshuanand

Hi @VinayB,
I have just created one VM using Azurecloud marketplace image mentioned below:
source_image_reference {
publisher = "azurecyclecloud"
offer     = "azure-cyclecloud"
sku       = "cyclecloud8-gen2"
version   = "latest"
}
It will automatically configure/install the cyclecloud in vm, now i want the initial setup of azure cycle cloud using terraform, is it even possible?

@anshuanand update the details by editing the Qs with more details so that community can check for possible solutions.

Hi @NaveenSharma i have edited the question and added the images as well.
Thanks for the suggestion.
